# scroll bar does not work?

Tags: android, xml, layout

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv_chat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout_bottom"
    android:background="#ffffffff" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_chatrecord"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If I add `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` in the `LinearLayout` , the `ScrollView` can't work.
When I put view in `LinearLayout` all the time,the view will appear from the bottom up which is I want.While the result is `ScrollView` can't work,the view put first can't be seen.How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" not needed with LinearLayout.

Comment: It works when I put android:layout_gravity="bottom" from LinearLayout to ScrollView.